# SPARQL search for first binding then stop

Tags: sparql

I have some stock data and I want to find the stock closing price two days following an event in which ?date was bound:

```
     BIND (?date + \"P2D\"^^xsd:dayTimeDuration As ?doe)
     ?event <http://www.foo.com/stock/date> ?doe.
     ?event <http://www.foo.com/stock/close> ?close.
```

I can think of ways to increment the 2 but I want to stop as soon as I get a value for ?close. I want to increment "trading days" not really calendar days.
Is there an elegant way to keep incrementing "P2D" but then stop when I get a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do something like `SELECT` the closing values for every day in the week (or whatever the longest gap in trading is) starting 2 calendar days after `?doe`, then `ORDER BY` date, and `LIMIT 1`.

Elegant?  Maybe not.  But no stepping, and should be fairly fast.

Comment: Thanks, I like this answer.